# How convert a Swift string created with "\u{ea12}" back to its hex value / string "ea12"?

Tags: swift

TL;DR

A Swift string is created with a single character like this:

```
let iconCode = "\u{ea12}"
```

How can I use convert `iconCode` back to output the hex value `"ea12"` instead?

**Details:**

Several years ago a custom icon font was added to an iOS app. Back then the font was shipped with a CSS file declaring a css-class for each icon:

```
.icon-XYZ:before { content: '\ea12'; }    /* some icon */
```

This was translated into Swift to hardcode the icons into the app:

```
let icons: [String: String] = [
    "XYZ": "\u{ea12}",
    "abc": "\u{e07}",
    "123": "\u{2c}",
    ...
]

func getIcon(withId id: String) -> String {
    return icon[id] ?? ""
}
```

Meanwhile the CSS is lost and needs to be re-created. How can I do this:

```
func dumpCSS() {
     for (id, icon) in icons {
         guard let data = icon.data(using: .utf8) else { print("error"); return }
         let code = data.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
         print(".icon-\(id):before { content: '\\\(code)'; }")
     }
}

.icon-123:before { content: '\2c'; }       // OK
.icon-XYZ:before { content: '\eea892'; }   // wrong
.icon-abc:before { content: '\e0b887'; }   // wrong
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS escapes use the unicode code point value, so you should definitely not use the UTF8 encoding. Instead, use `unicodeScalars` to get all the code points in the string.

```
 for (id, icon) in icons {
     let codePoints = icon.unicodeScalars

     // assuming each icon can have multiple code points
     let escapeSequences = codePoints.map { "\\\(String($0.value, radix: 16))" }.joined()

     print(".icon-\(id):before { content: '\(escapeSequences)'; }")
 }
```